# Difference between 'I do have a bicycle' and 'I have a bicycle'

Tags: emphasis

I'm a native English speaker. I was talking with a friend who is a native Spanish speaker and is learning English. In English, I (the native English speaker) uses the expression 'I do have a bicycle' and my friend is confused about why I don't say 'I have a bicycle' since it is shorter.

Is there a grammatical reason or explanation behind the two forms? Are they interchangeable or are there cases where you must use one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker, you can feel there's a difference between "I do have a bicycle" and "I have a bicycle", and you'd know when to use one and not the other.

Those differences *are the rule*: using "do" before the verb *adds emphasis*.

It may emphasize contrast:

> Alice: I'd invite you on this exciting adventure, but you don't have a bicycle.
> Bob: No, I ***do*** have a bicycle.

or

> Alice: Do you get any exercise?
> Bob: I *do* have a bicycle, but I hardly use it at all.

or it may show excitement:

> Alice: I hope you can come with us on this exciting adventure. Do you have a bicycle?
> Bob: Yes, I ***do*** have a bicycle!

But it would be unnatural to use the emphatic "do" in a neutral context:

> Alice: What's in your garage?
> Bob: I **<del>do</del>** have a car, a bicycle, some tools and my workbench.